# How to add 3 element to an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array below. Inside it, i am storeing order status-es in a webshop.

```
    $rendeles_allapotok = array
(
    "0"=>"Új megrendelés",
    "1"=>"Függőben lévő",
    "2"=>"Feldolgozás alatt",
    "3"=>"Feldolgozva",
    "4"=>"Kiküldve",
    "5"=>"Postázva",
    "6"=>"Teljesítve",
    "7"=>"Sikertelen",
    "8"=>"Visszafizetve"
);
```

Now, this array has 2 element in each row, an id, and the status name.

But i want 3. I want to add a new parameter, the name will be product_back, and the value for that will be 0 or 1.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by **2 elements in each row**? what elements? and what rows?

Comment: Assuming the numerical keys are rows, I only see 1 element per row?

Comment: seems like you need a proper tutorial on how arrays work in PHP. Becaue you are getting it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking for is this i am not sure that you need a multi-dimensional array

> **Note:** I substituted the [array shorthand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php#115181) but it is not required

```
$rendeles_allapotok = [

    ['id'=>0, 'name'=>"Új megrendelés",   'product_back'=>0],
    ['id'=>1, 'name'=>"Függőben lévő",    'product_back'=>0],
    ['id'=>2, 'name'=>"Feldolgozás alatt",'product_back'=>0],
    ['id'=>3, 'name'=>"Feldolgozva",      'product_back'=>0],
    ['id'=>4, 'name'=>"Kiküldve",         'product_back'=>0],
    ['id'=>5, 'name'=>"Postázva",         'product_back'=>0],
    ['id'=>6, 'name'=>"Teljesítve",       'product_back'=>0],
    ['id'=>7, 'name'=>"Sikertelen",       'product_back'=>0],
    ['id'=>8, 'name'=>"Visszafizetve",    'product_back'=>0]
];
```

then to access the items in a loop you could do something like this

```
foreach($rendeles_allapotok as $row){
       echo "ID: {$row['id']}\n".
            "NAME: {$row['name']}\n";
       echo "Product Back:" . $row['product_back']==1?'  True':'  false';

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an example, the array would have another array in it with both fields.

```
$rendeles_allapotok = array
(
    "0"=>array("name"=>"Új megrendelés","product_bak"=>"0"),
    "1"=>array("name"=>"Függőben lévő","product_bak"=>"1")
);
```

Comment: Thank you to, but someone writed before you, and i have to accept his answer. But yours is the same and usefull to.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for.  You cannot store more than one value in an array without the use of a nested or multi dimensional array.

```
$rendeles_allapotok = array
(
    "0"=> array( 'product_back' => 0, 'status' => "Új megrendelés" ),
    "1"=> array( 'product_back' => 0, 'status' => "Függőben lévő" ),
    "2"=> array( 'product_back' => 0, 'status' => "Feldolgozás alatt" ),
    "3"=> array( 'product_back' => 0, 'status' => "Feldolgozva" ),
    "4"=> array( 'product_back' => 0, 'status' => "Kiküldve" ),
    "5"=> array( 'product_back' => 0, 'status' => "Postázva" ),
    "6"=> array( 'product_back' => 0, 'status' => "Teljesítve" ),
    "7"=> array( 'product_back' => 0, 'status' => "Sikertelen" ),
    "8"=> array( 'product_back' => 0, 'status' => "Visszafizetve )"
);
```

and to access it you would do this

```
echo $rendeles_allapotok[1]['status'];
echo $rendeles_allapotok[1]['product_back'];
```